# How can I add something to my custom listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I made a custom listbox but when I push the button show every language nothing is showing. How can I fix this. When I delete the listbox style it just works fine. It's all in C#.
I hope you can help me.

greetings
Elias

```
<ListBox x:Name="lsbResultaatTaal"
             Foreground="Black"
             FontSize="15"
             Grid.Row="1"
             Margin="528,56,0,0" 
             Height="450" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             Width="233">
    

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{d:SampleData ItemCount=5}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    <ListBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListBox">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Style>

    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
            <Border Width="230" Height="450"
                        CornerRadius="9"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: You must include `ItemsPresenter` in ControlTemplate of `ListBox.Template`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/listbox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#listbox-parts

Answer (score 0):

You can set style in resources

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" /> 
                <!-- 
                     Why you choose same background color when hover listbox 
                     Maybe same color your background and foreground
                -->
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

**OR**

Can you try below changes:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>


<ContentPresenter
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Content="{Binding YourProp}" />
```